# search in a multidimensional list in python

Tags: python, list, contains

I have a list of tuples, namely `F = [(1,2,1), (2,3,0), (1,2,4)]`.

If I want to check whether `(1,2,1)` exists in the `F` I use `F.__contains__((1,2,1))`.

But how can I check whether `(1,2,just any number)` or `(1,just any number,just any number)` exists in the list?

I used `F.__contains__((1,2,True))` but didn't work correctly.

Comment: Never use `__contains__` directly, don't use dunder methods directly

Comment: `F.__contains__((1,2,True))` returns `True`. Why not just use `ìn` ? `(1,2,True) in F`

Comment: you're going to have to use `any`: `any(x[0:2] == (1,2) for x in F)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment Mohammad asked for a more generic search method. Here's one way to do it.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

F = [(1,2,1), (2,3,0), (1,2,4)]

def search_2d_list(needle, haystack):
    def equal_or_none(row):
        return all(q is None or q == i for q, i in zip_longest(needle, row))
    return any(equal_or_none(row) for row in haystack)
```

Results from terminal

```
>>> search_2d_list((1,), F)
True
>>> search_2d_list((1,2), F)
True
>>> search_2d_list((1,2,1), F)
True
>>> search_2d_list((1,2,3), F)
False
>>> search_2d_list((2,2,3), F)
False
>>> search_2d_list((2,2), F)
False
>>> search_2d_list((2,None,2), F)
False
>>> search_2d_list((2,None,0), F)
True
```

Comment: If you may need to match None in searches, you could define a class Wildcard and use that instead of None.

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> T = (1, 2)
>>> F = [(1,2,1), (2,3,0), (1,2,4)]
>>> any(filter(lambda x:x[:2]==T, F))
True
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing?

Comment: 'filter' keeps elements passing the test, and 'any' returns False if this list os empty.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the special method `__contains__` directly as mentioned by others here. Use the membership operator `in` which performs the same task.

**Code**

```py
F = [(1,2,1), (2,3,0), (1,2,4)]

print((1, 2) in [element[:2] for element in F])  # True
```

Comment: but what about the case when searching for `(1, anynumber, 2)` or `(1, anynumber, anynumber)` ?

Comment: If this is the case, I think you need a chain of `if-else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
(1, 2) in [x[:-1] for x in F]
```

Note as already commented do not use contains directly

Comment: this doesn't shortcut. better use any

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry what do you mean by shortcut? I am unfamiliar

Comment: Agree on any. Try `any(x[:2] == (1, 2) for x in F)`. Low memory footprint, no unnecessary comparisons.

Comment: I mean if the list has 400000 elements and the first element matches, you're creating the list anyway.

Comment: I think the correct term is _short circuit_, btw. Any will return True as soon as it encounters a truthy result. If you do list comprehensions you will do all calculations first, create a potentially huge list, and then search that.

Comment: but what about the case when searching for `(1, anynumber, 2)` or `(1, anynumber, anynumber)` ?